# Adding a populated column to an existing table

Tags: sql, heidisql

I have 2 table that have table counts in them. Something like 
Table 1:

```
New_Counts
100
```

Table 2:

```
Old_Counts
97
```

I want to create a single QC table so I can eventually check that the counts are increasing:

```
New_Counts|Old_Counts
100|97
```

Any ideas how to do this in SQL? A join won't work since the counts are never the same.

Comment: If there's more than one row in both tables how would you determine which values are shown together?

Answer (score 0):

```
select newcount,oldcount
from (select
    (select count(*) newcount from table1) newcount,
    (select count(*) oldcount from table2) oldcount
    from dual);
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23327734)

Comment: I agree with your argument however in my opinion the is rudimentary SQL that warrants an example for those that want to learn.