# SQL on Self Table Join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do a simple self-join SQL and a join to a 2nd table and for the life of me I can't figure it out. I've done some research and can't seem to glean the answer from similar questions. This query is for MS-Access running in VB.NET.

I have 2 tables:

```
TodaysTeams
-----------
TeamNum  PlayerName PlayerID
-------  ---------- --------
   1     Mark       100
   1     Brian      101
   2     Mike       102
   2     Mike       102
```

(Note the last 2 rows above are not a typo. In this case a player can be paired with themselves to form a team)

```
TodaysTeamsPoints
-----------------
TeamNum    Points
-------    ------
   1         90
   2         85
```

The result I want is (2 rows, 1 for each team):

```
TeamNum  PlayerName1  PlayerName2  Points
-------  -----------  -----------  ------
   1     Mark         Brian          90
   2     Mike         Mike           85
```

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.TeamNum, A.PlayerName as PlayerName1, B.PlayerName    AS PlayerName2, C.Points
FROM            ((TodaysTeams A INNER JOIN
                     TodaysTeamsPoints C ON A.TeamNum = C.TeamNum)    INNER JOIN
                     TodaysTeams B ON A.TeamNum = B.TeamNum)
ORDER BY C.Points DESC
```

I know I am missing another join as I'm returning a cartesian produce (i.e. too many rows).

I would appreciate help as to what I am missing here.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this thread.  It gives an example of how to move rows into columns.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693468/adding-a-populated-column-to-an-existing-table/56693982#56693982

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT ttp.TeamNum, MIN(tt.PlayerName) as PlayerName1, 
       MAX(tt.PlayerName) as PlayerName2,
       ttp.Points
FROM TodaysTeamsPoints as ttp INNER JOIN
     TodaysTeams as tt 
     ON tt.TeamNum = ttp.TeamNum
GROUP BY ttp.TeamNum, ttp.Points
ORDER BY ttp.Points DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! I obviously didn't think of that but that did the trick. A minor note that you had a typo in the GROUP BY, it should have been ttp.TeamNum, ttp.Points (the "p" was omitted from ttp.TeamNum).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Gordon's suggested method will work well providing that there are at most two players per team, the method breaks down if ever you add another team member and wish to display them in a separate column.

The difficulty in displaying the data in a manner that you can describe logically but cannot easily produce using a query usually implies that the database structure is sub optimal.

For your particular setup, I would personally recommend the following structure:

```
+---------------+           +----------+------------+
|    Players    |           | PlayerID | PlayerName |
+---------------+           +----------+------------+
| PlayerID (PK) |           |      100 | Mark       |
| PlayerName    |           |      101 | Brian      |
+---------------+           |      102 | Mike       |
                            +----------+------------+
```

```
+-------------+             +--------+----------+
|    Teams    |             | TeamID | TeamName |
+-------------+             +--------+----------+
| TeamID (PK) |             |      1 | Team1    |
| TeamName    |             |      2 | Team2    |
+-------------+             +--------+----------+
```

```
+-------------------+       +--------+--------------+----------+
|    TeamPlayers    |       | TeamID | TeamPlayerID | PlayerID |
+-------------------+       +--------+--------------+----------+
| TeamID (PK)       |       |      1 |            1 |      100 |
| TeamPlayerID (PK) |       |      1 |            2 |      101 |
| PlayerID (FK)     |       |      2 |            1 |      102 |
+-------------------+       |      2 |            2 |      102 |
                            +--------+--------------+----------+
```

Using this method, you can use condition aggregation or a crosstab query pivoting on the `TeamPlayerID` to produce each of your columns, and you would not be limited to two columns.